# Qt sqlite, SELECT и bindValue, как это связать?

Tags: qt, sqlite, select

Имеется примерно такой код:

```
QSqlQuery query2;
QString val=QString::number(passAs);
query2.exec("SELECT id, Name FROM STB_tasks WHERE UserID=:UserID");

query2.bindValue(":UserID", QVariant(val));
while (query2.next())
{ ... }
```

Собственно вопрос, как это связать, поскольку почти все, что нашел, касается лишь INSERT, а там все действительно работает, но конкретно данная конструкция не взлетает.
    QT 5.8, Win10x64, minGW 5.1, sqlite 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю, вам нужно это:

```
QSqlQuery query2;
query.prepare("SELECT id, Name FROM STB_tasks WHERE UserID=:UserID");
query.bindValue(":UserID", 2);
query.exec();
```

Когда выполняется метод `prepare`, сам запрос не выполняется, а лишь отправляется на сервер и хранится там до того, как вы отключитесь от базы данных. Когда вы выполните метод `exec`, на сервер отправится массив параметров и запрос будет выполнен. Обратите внимание, что если вы хотите выполнить этот же запрос ещё раз с другими параметрами, то не нужно снова вызывать метод prepare: нужно лишь заново отправить массив параметров и вызвать метод `exec`.